# How to assign different class for the same element?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I am trying to create conditional state for my class in Angular

I have something like

```
<div class='test' ng-class="(test=1:'class1',test=2:'class2',test=3:'class3')">
    <div>
        //more contents here
    </div>

</div>
```

basically I need to have a conditional statement to apply the class based from the test variable. so if test `test =1` i need `class1` and if `test =2` i need `class2`. My syntax is probably wrong here. Is that something Angular can do? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class='test' 
     ng-class="{'class1': test == 1, 'class2': test == 2, 'class3': test == 3}">
    <div>
        //more contents here
    </div>
</div>
```

Class to be applied should be the string key and the condition should be the value of the key-value pair. To be on the safer side, you can use single quote which is optional.

[<kbd>**DEMO**</kbd>](http://plnkr.co/edit/xrFg2NxWwL1j7XkHZzFP?p=preview)

Comment: @FlyingCat Check the [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/xrFg2NxWwL1j7XkHZzFP?p=preview).